# How to make a continuous TrackBar in c#?

Tags: c#, user-interface

How can I make a continuous trackbar in c# using VS2005? Right now, I have a trackbar but it's only letting me select the values that are ticks. How can I make the trackbar continuous?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the digital world, nothing is really continuous.  Just get it a large maximum value and it will feel continuous.